# want to move to different DIV on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 div's in my html page and 5 buttons.I want to got to 5th div by auto-scrolling when button 5 is clicked.But i dont want to use the position to scroll in x axis...i want to move with reference with div id.So how can i do that? Help me in jquery or javascript.

Comment: i guess you need something like [this](http://djpate.com/2011/01/01/animated-scrollto-effect-jquery-plugin/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kindly take a look at the following link

http://pastebin.com/Nav6aSQg

i have pasted the code over there.

```
enter code here
enter code here




<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function scroll(val)
{
    //alert(document.getElementById(val));
    document.getElementById(val).click()
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1" style="height:200px">
The content of your div1 here.
</div>

<div id="div2" style="height:200px">
The content of your div2 here.
</div>

<div id="div3" style="height:200px">
The content of your div3 here.
</div>

<div id="div4" style="height:200px">
The content of your div4 here.
</div>

<div id="div5" style="height:200px">
The content of your div5 here.
</div>

<div style="display:none;">
<a href="#div1" id="id1">Link Text Here</a>
<a href="#div2" id="id2">Link Text Here</a>
<a href="#div3" id="id3">Link Text Here</a>
<a href="#div4" id="id4">Link Text Here</a>
<a href="#div5" id="id5">Link Text Here</a>
</div>


<input type="button" onclick="scroll('id1')" value="button1"></input>
<input type="button" onclick="scroll('id2')" value="button2"></input>
<input type="button" onclick="scroll('id3')" value="button3"></input>
<input type="button" onclick="scroll('id4')" value="button4"></input>
<input type="button" onclick="scroll('id5')" value="button5"></input>


</body>
</html>

enter code here
```

Answer (score 8):

### Using `scrollTop()` and the `<div>` position:

#### Non-animated:

```
var $divs = $('div'),
    $buttons = $('button');

$buttons.live('click', function ()
{
    var $this = $(this),
        index = $buttons.index(this);
        
    $(window).scrollTop($divs.eq(index).offset().top);
});
```

***[Demo 1a →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/jKXxr/)***

#### Animated:

```
var $divs = $('div'),
    $buttons = $('button'),
    $hb = $('html, body');

$buttons.live('click', function ()
{
    var $this = $(this),
        index = $buttons.index(this);
        
    $hb.animate({scrollTop: $divs.eq(index).offset().top + 'px'});
});
```

***[Demo 1b →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/jKXxr/1/)***

---

### Using the `<div>` id:

```
// snip...
$buttons.live('click', function ()
{
    var $this = $(this),
        index = $buttons.index(this);

    window.location.hash = $divs.eq(index).attr('id');
});
```

***[Demo 2 →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/VeGyF/1/)***

Answer (score 2):

Not probably the exact solution, but the easiest way to achieve this kind of solution is something like:

Let the button is;

```
<Button><a href="#move_here" class="myClass"> Click It </a></Button>
```

and the `DIV` where you want to move on `Button Click` is;

```
<div>
    <a name="move_here"></a>
    ...div content here...
</div>
```

I hope, you've noticed `move_here`.

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked with id you can try it out

```html
<a href="#art"><button class="button">see</button></a>

<div id="art" class="artpage"><div>
```